# Setting a value in PHP when i click on a button

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, variables

I have to change a value when the user clicks on a button but I don't know how to do that:

```
foreach (Carteras::listado_nombre($nombre_anunciante) as $registro) {
?>
                    <tr>

                        <td><p id="nowrap"><?= $registro["rut"] ?></p></td>
                        <td><?= $registro["nombre_anunciante"] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $registro["canal"] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $registro["nombre_vendedor"] ?></td>
                        <td>$<?= $registro["Inversión 2015"] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $registro["estado"] ?></td>
                        <td> <a href="http://voldemort.valpo.elmercurio.org/practica/registros/venta detalle/buscar.php">Detalle</a></td>
                    </tr>
        <?php
                    }
```

When the user clicks on the word Detalle i want to set the nombre_anunciante  to `$registro["nombre_anunciante"]`. I want to do this because `Carteras::lista_nombre` searches with a like in sql to obtain all the names with that word, so i want to complete the name when the user clicks on the name that he wants.

Comment: `buscar.php?name=whatever`?

Comment: in buscar.php the user obtains the detail of the "nombre_anunciante" using nombre_anunciante as a parameter, so i have to change the value inside the foreach, only if the user clicks on the Detalle word